# Groupby and 'transpose the data to a new dataframe and creating column names

Tags: python

I'll preface this by saying I'd consider myself inexperienced in both python and coding in general.

I have a dataframe that I want groupby the site and then move the data into a new dataframe that uses the year as the column headings, I can't think what this would be called, its not really a transpose as there can be years missing (unless you can somehow transpose and match column names to df['year'])

df =

| site | year | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2010 | 10 |
| a | 2011 | 12 |
| a | 2012 | 7 |
| a | 2013 | 45 |
| b | 2010 | 21 |
| b | 2012 | 45 |
| b | 2013 | 54 |
| c | 2010 | 17 |
| c | 2011 | 32 |
| c | 2012 | 24 |

What I want to end up with is something like this

| site | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 12 | 7 | 45 |
| b | 21 |  | 45 | 54 |
| c | 17 | 32 | 24 |  |

This gets me some of the way there, but will not work where there is missing data - I'm not sure how to proceeed and incorporate the taking the years and creating the new columns.

df.groupby('site')['data'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()

I feel it shouldn't be difficult, and that I just can't come up with the right keywords to search for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"site": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
"year": [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012],
"data": [10, 12, 7, 45, 21, 45, 54, 17, 32, 24]})

df = df.set_index(["site", "year"])
new_df = df.pivot_table(values="data", index="site", columns="year",     
fill_value=0)
new_df = new_df.sort_index(axis=1)

print(new_df)
```

This should help you.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after - didn't really know pandas had a pivot function.